# Is it a good idea to enroll in Apple Developer Program now?

Tags: developer-program

I heard that Apple is going to make the Developer Program for building and distributing iOS apps free? Is that true? Is it a good idea to pay $99 now or should I just wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When iOS 9 releases, anyone will be able to build apps and deploy them on their devices without needing to join the developer program. However, you will not be able to distribute the app to the app store without joining the dev program.

Comment: I can confirm that, I'm running Xcode 7 Beta and have been testing my app on my iPhone.